# Computer can't boot

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, power

I have a 1 year old PC and the last weeks, when I press the ON button the PC doesn't power on ( Like I didn't press the ON button ). I have to plug and unplug a few times the power cord in order to make it work. At the start this happened once in 10 boots. Now it happens much more frequently to the point that when I press the power on button it never even opens if I don't do the cord switch thingy. Very rarely also, the PC shut downs for no reason and no warning, even when idle.

The important fact to note here is, the green light on the motherboard is always on, even when the PC doesn't power on.

What should I do? Is it a Power Supply failure or a motherboard? My power supply is a high end corsair model, AX850 and my motherboard a high end ASUS.

Comment: I had this happen... the problem was actually the front panel electronics in the case that the power button is attached to.  [This](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/urgent-boot-a-motherboard-with-no-power-button.159621/) thread explains how to test by jumping pins 6 and 8 of the front panel connector.  Double check your MB documentation for correct pins, but this is pretty standard connector.

Comment: PS - that linked thread goes off in the wrong direction with the first answers =]

Comment: In most cases it is the button wiring in the front panel - loose connections etc., Check your power and reset button + mic + headphone (if there is) with the motherboard. Many times this has been incorrect in my experience. You will find the connection details with the ASUS motherboard manual when you got it (or may be online too)